# How to delete a file that already exists in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I currently have my program creating an XML file on start and i want it to delete the file at the very end but nothing i do will delete the file. I have been using

```
File.Delete (Application.dataPath + "File.xml");
```

and then refreshing but the file doesn't delete.

does anyone have anything that might be able to help me?

Comment: What is the value of `Application.dataPath` when you debug through?

Answer (score 5):

When you delete file from the Editor with `File.Delete`, you have to call [`AssetDatabase.Refresh()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetDatabase.Refresh.html) to import any changed assets. This likely the issue.

---

If you have already done that but the file is still there you're likely deleting the wrong file. The `Application.dataPath` path points to the `<ProjectName>/Assets` directory so your `File.xml` file is expected to be in `<ProjectName>/Assets` for the deletion to work.

---

Finally, when deleting files in the Editor, I would recommend that you use [`FileUtil.DeleteFileOrDirectory`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/FileUtil.DeleteFileOrDirectory.html) from the `UnityEditor` namespace instead of `File.Delete` then refresh it with `AssetDatabase.Refresh()`. It is specially designed to be used in the Editor to delete files and directories.

```
string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.dataPath, "File.xml");
UnityEditor.FileUtil.DeleteFileOrDirectory(path);
AssetDatabase.Refresh();
```

Comment: it works if i move the xml file into the assets folder but when it creates it is only placed in the games folder not assets.

Comment: *"when it creates it is only placed in the games folder not assets"* Can you elaborate more on this? What creates what?

Comment: When my program creates the xml file, it makes it in my project folder. And while the xml file is in the assets folder it can be deleted but the xml file is not being created there.

Comment: *"When my program creates the xml file, it makes it in my project folder."* Where in your project folder? You want to create the xml uring run-time? You need to post the code that is creating the xml file. At this point, your question is incomplete.